# Is there any way to write a function that can output to either std::io::Write or std::fmt::Formatter?

Tags: rust

I want to write a function that produces some text, like so:

```rust
fn produce_stuff(/* ??? */) -> Result<()> {
    write!(...);
    write!(...);
    write!(...);
    ...
}
```

I want to be able to use this function in two contexts:

1. Use it to output to an IO writer—something like `produce_text(io.stdout())`.
2. Use it as a helper function when implementing `Display` — something like this:

```rust
struct Foo { ... }
impl Display for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        ...
        produce_text(f);
        ...
    }
}
```

It seems like each of these use cases would require a different signature for `produce_text`. For #1, the function would need to take something that implements `std::io::Write`, and for #2 it would need to take a `std::fmt::Formatter`.

I suppose I could write it as a macro instead of as a function (similar to how `write!` is a macro that works both in both contexts), but it somehow feels wrong to use a macro for this.

Comment: that exactly what Display is for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to implement [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html).

When your `Foo` implements `Display`, you can use it with any implementation of `Write`, including `io::Stdout`:

```rust
use std::{
    io::{self, Write},
    fmt,
};

struct Foo {
    field: u16,
}
impl fmt::Display for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Foo({})", self.field)
    }
}

fn main() {
    write!(io::stdout(), "{}", Foo{field: 3}).unwrap();
}
```

You don't have to write your own macro; just use `write!`. This should not feel wrong, it's the normal way.

There's no runtime cost related to the `"{}"` argument: it's parsed at compile time (in a compiler built-in), which makes the `write!(w, "{}", displayable)` call efficient.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e5b2c76c99b7f9765e42ef83512c7e45)

Comment: In this case, my text-producing function isn't really associated with any particular type, so the choice of which type to implement Display is non-obvious. I guess I can just define an empty dummy struct and implement Display on that.

Comment: @Will There's usually a semantic association which makes it possible to define a useful enough struct which implements Display. And reuse it in other Display. It doesn't have to own its data. I do that in Termimad: https://github.com/Canop/termimad/blob/master/src/displayable_line.rs